# Warning C26435 Function CXxxx::DoDataExchange should specify exactly one of `virtual`, `override`, or `final` (c.128)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

Here is another code analysis warning:

> Warning [`C26435`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26435?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C26435)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160) Function `CAssignSelectedColumnDlg::DoDataExchange` should specify exactly one of `virtual`, `override`, or `final` (c.128).

Example (boilerplate MFC code):

```
void CAssignSelectedColumnDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
...
...
}
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, I need to attach either:

- `override` or
- `final`

... to the function declaration in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The link you posted has another link in it:

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override

You can trust the authors :)

> Editors:
>
> ```
> Bjarne Stroustrup
> Herb Sutter
> ```

---

For others benefit:

> `void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) final;`

Comment: Thank you. In my situation then, I would use the keyword `final` because I would not be deriving a new class from my dialog. That is how I understand this.

Comment: `final` is the correct keyword in this situation. You'd use `override` if the class is intended to be derived from, except when it is the base class of a class hierarchy, in which case the `virtual` keyword is required. The diagnostic is meant to guard against accidentally hiding a `virtual` class member in a derived class with a non-`virtual` class member of the same signature rather than overriding it. This would be legal code that compiles just fine, producing a program that works most of the time. That makes finding this bug particularly challenging.